# What kind of overhead does separating code into dlls cause

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that has 78 projects in it.

The solution uses Prism a lot, and prism likes things in separate dlls.

The current iteration I am in has me adding some more UI components.  This particular set of UI components could be put in the same project as an existing set.

I am wondering if I should do that or if I should make a new project (since it is a separate set of UI controls).

**Can someone tell me what the drawbacks are to having code in a separate dll?**

By drawbacks I am looking at user experience and build speed.

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone tell me what the drawbacks are (performance wise) to having code in a separate dll?

The main difference is in how the CLR loads the assemblies.  There is a bit more overhead involved in loading up the extra assembly.

That being said, the assembly won't be loaded at startup (unless it's used at startup), which means that the application's overall startup time may actually improve.

Once everything is loaded and running, there should be no performance difference between using a single assembly or multiple assemblies.

Instead of focusing on the performance aspects of separating the projects, I would recommend focusing on the difference in deployment and maintenance.  If the projects make sense as separate projects, and keeping them separate makes your solution more maintainable, I would separate them.  If it's only adding complexity in your deployment and build environment, and the types are going to always be used together, I would keep them together.

Comment: On the flip side, the lazy nature of DLL loading may mean that your application lags when features are used for the first time (in a recent project with dozens of dependencies, the lag was bad enough that we were forced to make dummy calls at startup to avoid a bad user experience).